# Making a string translation ready with html in it

Tags: translation

I can make a simple translation string like this:

```
<?php _e('Hello world','text-domain'); ?>
```

But how to make a translation string if there is a markup in it? For example this:

```
<?php _e('<span>Hello</span> world','text-domain'); ?>
```

Is the above correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Localizing a string with html markup inside the string can be a very opinionated story as you can see from one of [my questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/135866/31545) when I started out.

I would not say you are right, neither would I say that you are wrong, but I would say that your method is not prefered.

If you have a look at [**I18n for WordPress Developers**](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers), you'll see that you should use `printf()` and placeholders when you have variables inside a string, well, the same applies for markup. My emphasis, you should never translate html tags, always use html tags outside of your string.

An example, with what I've just covered, should render a string like this

```
printf(__( '%s Hello %s world', 'textdomain' ), '<span>', '</span>' );
```

Answer (score 0):

It works.

```
 echo '<span>' . esc_html__( 'Hello world', 'textdomain' ) . '</span>';
```